# HTML audio tag can not jump to true range start for request

Tags: audio, html5-audio

In the following audio jump demo, `1MnxnMOPlkOJO.mp3` can be clicked normally and then passed the correct range start in request and played immediately. `1MnxnMOPlkOJO.aac` does not, it will continue to download from the buffered location to the post-jump content location before it starts playing.

Why is that?

This html runs in MacBook Pro Chrome 120.0.6099.216 (arm64)

```html
<body>
    <audio id="audio-player" controls>
        <source src="https://sjc1.vultrobjects.com/tw-audio/1MnxnMOPlkOJO.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
    <div>
        <button onclick="jumpToTime(10)">10:00</button>
        <button onclick="jumpToTime(20)">20:00</button>
        <button onclick="jumpToTime(30)">30:00</button>
    </div>
    
    <audio id="audio-player1" controls>
        <source src="https://sjc1.vultrobjects.com/tw-audio/1MnxnMOPlkOJO.aac" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
    <div>
        <button onclick="jumpToTime1(10)">10:00</button>
        <button onclick="jumpToTime1(20)">20:00</button>
        <button onclick="jumpToTime1(70)">1:10:00</button>
    </div>

    <script>
        const audioPlayer = document.getElementById('audio-player');

        function jumpToTime(minutes) {
            audioPlayer.currentTime = minutes * 60;
        }

        const audioPlayer1 = document.getElementById('audio-player1');
        function jumpToTime1(minutes) {
            audioPlayer1.currentTime = minutes * 60;
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

`1MnxnMOPlkOJO.aac` was merged directly from the aac I downloaded via an m3u8 file, and `1MnxnMOPlkOJO.mp3` was converted to mp3 format with ffmpeg. But I don't want ffmpeg to convert again, how can I solve the above problem?